# My create action can't access the .new_record? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4.0 application I have a form and its corresponding create action. They both work perfectly:

**view form:**

```
<%= form_for @user_friendship, method: :post do |f| %>

    <div class="form form-actions">     

        <%= f.text_field :friend_id, value: @friend.id %>
        <%#= f.button :submit #=> This creates a User_friendship %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", profile_path(@friend.profile_name), class: 'btn' %>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

**its create action**

```
def create
    if params[:friend_id]

        @friend = User.find_by_id(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])

        logger.fatal "Here is the friend:"
        logger.fatal @friend.inspect

    else

    end

    if @friend

        @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user,@friend)

        logger.fatal @user_friendship.inspect

#       if @user_friendship.new_record?
#           flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating that friend request"
#       else
#           flash[:success] = "Friend request sent to " + @friend.first_name
#       end

        redirect_to profile_path(@friend.profile_name), status: 302


    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required!"
        redirect_to root_path, status: 302
    end 
end
```

But when I uncomment these lines:

```
    if @user_friendship.new_record?
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating that friend request"
    else
            flash[:success] = "Friend request sent to " + @friend.first_name
    end
```

I get this error message:

```
NoMethodError in UserFriendshipsController#create
undefined method `new_record?' for #<Mail::Message:0x00000104aae768>
```

I have no idea where is this error is coming from (is it a problem with a mailer?) so please tell me if I need to post more information.

I find that `Mail::Message` part really strange...what is this object?

**model**

```
def self.request(user1, user2)
    friendship1 = []

    transaction do
        friendship1 = create!(user_id: user1.id, friend_id: user2.id, state: 'pending')
        friendship2 = create!(user_id: user2.id, friend_id: user1.id, state: 'requested') 
    end

    friendship1.send_request_email
end

def send_request_email
    UserNotifier.friend_requested(id).deliver
end
```

**mailer:**

```
def friend_requested(user_friendship_id)


    user_friendship = UserFriendship.find(user_friendship_id)

    @user = user_friendship.user
    @friend = user_friendship.friend


    mail to: @friend.email,
         subject: @user.first_name + " wants to be your friend!"
end
```

Comment: Show the definition of `UserFriendship.request` and make sure there is only one `UserFriendship` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user_friendship` is assigned the value which is return from calling `UserFriendship.request(...)`.  It appears that method returns a mail object (are you sending an email notification there as the last line in the method?).  Try returning the UserFriendship object from that method.

Edit:

Better yet, just do `@user_friendship = UserFriendship.create(current_user, @friend)` and then send an email in an after_create callback.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are getting a Mail::Message object in the UserFriendship.request call. Does this object have a method "new_record?" ?. Probably not.

Comment: I thought a class method would have all the methods (including new_record?) available to its model?

Comment: Oh wait I got you now, because ruby methods automatically return their last result

Comment: Well but you are not getting an object of type UserFriendship (which I assume is the model). You are getting an object of type Mail::Message. What you need to do is to add a "return friendship1" at the end of the "request" method.